# How to dequeue child theme styles?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, storefront

I'm starting from a blank Storefront child theme template I found on GitHub. The child theme's `style.css` contains some author information but everything is commented out. A GTmetrix scan shows that this stylesheet file is being loaded and recommends that I load it inline, but I'm thinking since it's essentially empty, why load it at all?

I add my style customizations in the Additional CSS box of the Wordpress Customizer, so I wish to dequeue the enpty child theme's `style.css` and hopefully optimize page load speed a little bit.

So I added the following to my functions.php:

```
/* Dequeue Storefront Child Theme style.css */

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_storefront_child_theme_style ');

function dequeue_storefront_child_theme_style() {
    wp_dequeue_style(' storefront-child-style ');
}
```

But I can see it is still being loaded in the page source (and on GTmetrix re-scan).

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='storefront-child-style-css' href='https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/storefront-child-theme/style.css?ver=1.0.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

So my questions are, am I correct in my assumption that this blank stylesheet ise unnecessary because it slows down page load? And how do I go about dequeueing it properly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The style.css file is a necessary file as per the [WordPress docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) as it tells WordPress basic info about the theme, including the fact that it is a child theme with a particular parent.

Answer (score 0):

using the code above was not working because it has a space in this 'dequeue_storefront_child_theme_style '  and ' storefront-child-style '
After fixing this, this code worked for me with a higher priority:
You should probably not set it that high but pick a value suited to you.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_storefront_child_theme_style',9999);

function dequeue_storefront_child_theme_style() {
    wp_dequeue_style('storefront-child-style');
}
```